# notificaciones desde service worker

Tags: javascript, pwa

Saludos tengo una función para enviar notificaciones pero dejo de funcionar

```js
const activateN = async ()=>{
        const sw = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()
        await Notification.requestPermission()
        if(sw){
            sw.sendNotification('mensaje recivido',{
                body:'has recivido un mensaje'
            })
        }else{
            new Notification('mensaje recivido',{
                body:'has recivido un mensaje'
            })
        }
    }
```

pero chrome me marca error aqui

```js
sw.sendNotification('mensaje recivido',{
                    body:'has recivido un mensaje'
                })
```

Comment: A mí me funciona. Qué dice el error?

Comment: cambie de sendNotification a showNotification, creo que no fue necesario al parecer era que mi internet no habia activado el service worker